# Creating Nested li using angular 2.3.1

Tags: angular

I am newbie in angular js 2.I am using Version 2.3.1.I am to display a list of elements upto nth level coming from Json. Can Anybody me creating the same.Help will be greatly appreciated. The Sample JSON is :

```
 data = [
    {
        label: 'a1',
        subs: [
            {
                label: 'a11',
                subs: [
                    {
                        label: 'a111',
                        subs: [
                            {
                                label: 'a1111',
                                subs : [
                                {   label:"dollar"
                                }
                                    ]
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'a1112'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'a112'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'a12',
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'b1',
        subs: [
            {
                label: 'b11',
            },
            {
                label: 'b12',
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: share your code.. how you have tried so far

Comment: How exactly do you want this to look like when displayed?  it's not really clear what this data means, to even figure out what a list might look like.

Comment: @tanmay actually i am trying to implement but it is not working

Comment: @claies here data is simple Json data which is coming from backend and i want tree like like..i.e. on the click of first element another opens and so on.